# Is it possible to "unpool" a pooled variance if the population variances are not equal?

Tags: variance, population, pooling

I recognize that if the population variances are not equal, it's not really a pooled variance to start with, but I wanted to keep the question succinct. The scenario here is that I begin with a sample that has a certain mean and variance due to two "features", A and B. I can then take a second sample that varies only due to feature A.

Intuitively, it seems like the features could be modeled as populations, and in my first sample I actually observe the pooled mean and variance of the two populations A and B. In the second sample, I observe the mean and variance of only population A.

If this was truly a pooled variance, I think it would be fairly straightforward to back out the variance of B, so long as my first sample size was greater than the second:
$$S^2_{AB}=\frac{(n_A-1)S^2_A+(n_B-1)S^2_B}{n_A+n_B-2}$$
$$S^2_B=\frac{S^2_{AB}(n_{AB}-2)-(n_A-1)S^2_A}{n_{AB}-n_A-1}\text{,$\;$using$\;$}n_B=n_{AB}-n_A$$

It's OK that $n_B$ is fairly meaningless here, since in this particular case I'm really just interested in tracking $S^2_B$ over time as these tests repeat.

But does this work if A and B are known to not have the same variance? Is there an alternative method?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Thor. Could you please explain what it means to "observe" a pooled mean and variance?  These are *statistics,* which by definition are not observed but are computed from data.  Your question appears to be an algebraic one concerning how to solve for some statistics in terms of some others, but it's not clear what statistics you know and which ones you want to compute.

Comment: Hi Thor, is it correctly understood if I rephrase your question as: "I am looking at a population that consists of two subpopulations A and B. I have a sample from the whole population of size $n_{AB}$, and estimated the population variance from that. Then I became aware of the two subpopulations and took a new sample of size $n_A$ only from A. I estimated the variance also in the new sample. Can I retrieve the variance of subpopulation B from these two estimated variances?" -- if this is the correct interpretation, then: do you know how big the fraction of A is in the total population?

Comment: @Ute, thanks for looking at this, and yes, this a good interpretation. But I think to answer your question I might just have to explain some more details. The context here is that I am running lab test experiments on electronic devices, where each experiment generates a single number as output. First, I run an experiment on a single device many times. Ideally, the results would be the same, but I see variance in the data that I know comes from two sources: 1. device physics of the electronics themselves, and 2. nondeterminism in the software. Second, in an attempt to isolate how much of the

Comment: variance comes from each source, I now run this experiment on many different devices. This gives me a distribution of means and variances for the experiment due solely to source A - the device physics of each device - since A and B are completely independent. So I assume that the variance of this result distribution equals the component of variance seen in my first experiment due to A. Now if I want to determine the component of variance seen in my experiment due to B, I am attempting to model this problem as a pooled variance that I observed (rather than calculated) in $I$, and where one

Comment: of the contributions to that pool is my observations in $II$. @whuber Hopefully that helps clarify my weird language here about observing what is normally a computed statistic.

Comment: I realize I'm making a lot of assumptions here, so please feel free to tell me the approach is totally wrong (I suspect it is because I know the variance due to device physics and software are not the same). Also, sorry these comments are a bit confusing - I had no idea they could only be edited for 5 minutes after they were written. (why?)

Comment: Thank you for the extra information, thor! I think it would be very helpful if you edit your question and add the scientific background. That could just be an extra paragraph in the end. One reason for asking to edit: it makes the question itself more understandable. Another: comments can get deleted after a while (automatically) // (why?) : I have the same problem with time limit. I guess it is because this feature is meant as a chat, and if you often edit a comment, it is not possible to react meaningfully. After all, it turns up in your inbox.

Comment: I am trying to understand your experiment - maybe it is a case for "mixed models" :-) In experiment $I$, you have 1 device + software. Do you assume that the physical device alone already produces random error there? because then in $II$, as fas as I understand, you would see many physical device errors + many software errors (???). Or can we assume that each one physical device would produce the same result over and over (different results for different devices), if only the software would not add error? [wait a bit with editing your post]

Comment: Am I right that A and B in your experiment stand for two different devices? and are these the only devices you have, and want to investigate?

Comment: Yes, a single device would produce error alone even if the software did not - manufacturing differences, temperature fluctuations, and even background/ambient radio signals would all contribute to that error. That's what I'm calling A (B being the error from the software), with experiments in $I$ on a single device observing both errors together. You're right that in $II$ there would be many device errors, so thinking about this a bit more, I see it's a bit of a leap to assume that the A in $I$ is the same as the variance across A's seen in $II$.

Comment: I think the software error (B) is not very dependent on the device though. The only way that could be the case is if for large device error changes across devices, the software error might have some scaling effects (the percentage error would be the same, but the absolute error would not).

To your final comment, there will be many devices available to experiment on and compare if needed (100s). There are two purposes to these experiments: 1. attempt to calibrate the readings so the devices can be used interchangeably, and 2. track software error over time.

Comment: @ute Since this seems to be getting unmanageably complex, maybe it would be best to start by assuming that the per-device differences can be reduced to just a constant and a scalar (a bias value plus a percentage multiplier). There's no "true" value, but all devices could be calibrated in this way to some reference. Given this simplification, is there a good way to simultaneously acquire these calibration coefficients while also determining error/variance of the experiment?